# How to create a collection in MongoDB using SPRING data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Am using Spring-Data-Mongo to access do CRUD operations on my mongo database. I execute the below line

```
DB db = mongoTemplate.getDb()
```

When am in debug mode I can see that db._collections properties has 4 values (collections that I inserted). But when I query for

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

I get zero collections back. Why is that? Same is also true when I do

```
db.getCollection("collectionName")
```

But I know the collections do exists because when I do something like

```
mongoTemplate.createCollection("collectionName");
```

I get an exception saying that collection already exists. Can anyone please explain what I might be missing

Answer (score 2):

**[MongoTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html)** provides a few methods for managing collections. The following example demonstrates some of the methods:

```
DBCollection collection = null;
if (!mongoTemplate.getCollectionNames().contains("collectionName")) {
    collection = mongoTemplate.createCollection("collectionName");
}

mongoTemplate.dropCollection("collectionName");
```

In the above, **[`getCollectionNames()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#getCollectionNames--)** returns a set of collection names and **[`dropCollection()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#dropCollection-java.lang.String-)** drops the collection.

Comment: how is this different from what am doing already? I have mentioned that mongoTemplate.getCollectionNames() results in zero collection

Comment: It's different because you are using the `db` object from `DB db = mongoTemplate.getDb()` to get the collection names `db.getCollectionNames()` instead of the `mongoTemplate` object.

Comment: I tired it, no luck still. ,mongotemplate.dropCollection("collectionName") seems to work though. Also mongoTemplate.collectionExists("collectionName") return false, when i expect it to return true

Answer (score 0):

Use MongoClient, MongoDatabase, and MongoIterable of com.mongodb.client and com.mongodb package.

```
MongoClient client = MongoClient(<host>, port);
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(<Name of the database>);
MongoIterable<String> = db.listCollectionNames();
```

And now you can iterate over all the names of the collections.

Additionally, you even can use MongoCollection class to get the Document from the specified collection. The `getCollection()` will create collection if not present.

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection(<Collection name>);
```